# Convert Maven `maven-assembly-plugin` to Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm converting a Java project from Maven to Gradle.

One of the `pom.xml` is using `maven-assembly-plugin` to package dependencies into a single zip file.

I'm using custom configuration to specify the dependencies to package like so:

```
group = 'com.company'
description = 'projectA'

configurations {
    ciPlugin
}

dependencies {
    ciPlugin group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version:'4.3.1'
}

jar {
    into('plugins') {
        from configurations.ciPlugin
    }
}
```

This works almost fine beside the fact I have the following files in the resulting zip file:

1. commons-codec-1.10.jar
2. commons-logging-1.2.jar
3. httpclient-4.5.3.jar
4. httpcore-4.4.6.jar

and when Maven runs it only has `httpclient-4.5.3.jar`.

Just for clarification, I'm not really packaging `httpclient`, I'm packaging private artifact but the behavior is the same.

How can I get only the direct dependency without transient ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following (e.g. after the `dependencies` block):

```
configurations.ciPlugin.transitive = false
```

This will turn off transitive dependencies for all artifacts in the `ciPlugin` configuration.